# How to call a public static variable from another class, change its value and then check that its changed from its original class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have declared a blank string in one class and need to access the same string from another class, then set it equal to another value and return that value to the original class and log it in the console. I've looked around for a solution but cant really figure out how to

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? I couldn't understand well what you want.

Comment: public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

 public static string choice = "";

I need to access this string from a different class firstly

Comment: Use `Controller.choice` where you want to access

Comment: Remove the `static` from the variable then use the solution from answer in  the duplicated question.